# i was afraid i was going to break (into - out) crying. what is the correct answer?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

i was afraid i was going to break (into - out) crying. what is the correct answer?

Can someone tell me which answer would be the correct one? Even it you think that both sound right, which one is grammatically more correct??

Comment: It's not really a matter of "correct grammar", but [idiomatically,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=going+to+break+down+crying%2Cgoing+to+break+out+crying%2Cgoing+to+break+into+tears&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) we *break **out** crying* or *break **down** crying* - but actually, we're much more likely to *break **into tears***.

Comment: Or *break out laughing*, *break **up** with a friend*, but *break with tradition*,  *break through a barrier*, a wave can *break over*, and the thief was caught trying to  *break into the house*, then tried to *break out of jail*. Idioms are tough -- you get no breaks. ""Break, break, break *on* thy cold gray stones, O Sea!," wrote Tennyson.

Comment: It is very common to say ***burst** into tears*

Comment: Have you searched for the meanings of "break into" and "break out"?